# creating IAM user with change password on login option using Terraform

Tags: terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws, pgp

I am trying to create IAM user via terraform with change password on login option. I am getting a **base-64 encoded PGP public key**, not sure how to decrypt it, tried **"pgp_decrypt"** data source but it is not working. I want this to work without installing/using Keybase. Can someone please let me know the step-by-step process to achieve this?
I have attached my code below for reference.

```
resource "aws_iam_user" "test_users" {
  name = "testuser"
}

resource "pgp_key" "pgp_gen" {
  name    = "krishna"
  email   = "mxxxxxxa@xxxxxx.com"
  comment = "Generated PGP Key for"
}

resource "aws_iam_user_login_profile" "user_password_gen" {
  user = "testuser"
  pgp_key = pgp_key.pgp_gen.public_key_base64
  password_reset_required = true
  depends_on = [aws_iam_user.test_users]
}

data "pgp_decrypt" "decrypt_private_key" {
  ciphertext  = aws_iam_user_login_profile.user_password_gen.encrypted_password
  private_key = pgp_key.pgp_gen.private_key
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want to *output* the password or have it as sensitive, but I was managed to make it work, this is my tf:

```
resource "pgp_key" "user01" {
  name    = "user01"
  email   = "user01@test.com"
  comment = "user01"
}

resource "aws_iam_user" "user01" {
  name          = "user01"
  force_destroy = true
}

resource "aws_iam_user_login_profile" "user01" {
  user                    = aws_iam_user.user01.name
  pgp_key                 = pgp_key.user01.public_key_base64
  password_reset_required = true
}

data "pgp_decrypt" "user01" {
  private_key         = pgp_key.user01.private_key
  ciphertext          = aws_iam_user_login_profile.user01.encrypted_password
  ciphertext_encoding = "base64"
}

output "password-user01" {
  value     = data.pgp_decrypt.user01.plaintext
  sensitive = true
}
```

With that, you should be able to see the password by running:

```
terraform output password-user01
```

If you are the only one working on it and don't mind having the password in your terminal, you can remove the `sensitive` field.

Or you can remove the *output* resource and run it manually to get the password:

```
terraform state show data.pgp_decrypt.user01
```

Let me know if it helps you.